# How to reset Ant Design DatePicker (RangePicker) state after closing and reopening a dropdown?

Tags: datepicker, antd

When I'm opening Ant Design RangePicker and changing mode to years or any other, how to make it show the default view again on dropdown close and reopen? This question is also about resetting the month that DatePicker shows after reopening DatePicker to the current one